# TextView heading and Button repeated underneath each name in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, button, textview

I've an application which is a list of contacts' names retrieved from Android phone's contacts' list.
I've tried to add in TextView which is like a heading above the ListView and Button above below the TextView. The TextView and Button were repeated below each name in the list. It looked like this

[image: ListView of the names with Heading & Button]

Not only that, the textview is above the list and button below the list too. It's odd.
I'm not sure how to make the TextView above the list and button to be below the list only.

Oh yes, please take a look at my java and xml layout codes thanks --
contacts_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/light_goldenrod"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textInform"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose a Friend to Create an Event"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:transcriptMode="normal" />


   <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnMain"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/yellow_btn"
       style="@style/ButtonText"
       android:text="Main Menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ContactsList.java

```
public class ContactsList extends ListActivity
{
    TextView contactName;
    ListView list;

    final Context context = this;   
    Cursor cursor;
    BuddyDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        Uri allContacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");

        Cursor c = managedQuery(allContacts, null, null, null, null);

        String[] columns = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
        int[] views = new int[]  {R.id.contactName};

        startManagingCursor(c);

        SimpleCursorAdapter friendsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_list, c, columns, views);
        this.setListAdapter(friendsAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        buddyDB.open();
        long name_id;
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

           Cursor cursor = null;

           cursor = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
           Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsList.this, Create_Events.class);
           intent.putExtra("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(buddyDB.KEY_NAME)));
           startActivity(intent);

        Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
        c.moveToPosition(position);

        TextView contactName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        String NameValue = contactName.getText().toString();        
        name_id = buddyDB.insertNames(NameValue);

        buddyDB.close();    
    } 
}
```

Please help me with this.
 Any help provided will be greatly appreciated. Thanks =)

Comment: You should consider having a header and footer for the listview http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a layout file as follows and name it as contacts_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/light_goldenrod"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Change the following:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter friendsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_list, c, columns, views);
```

to:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter friendsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_item, c, columns, views);
```

Comment: Hi, I did what you said but it partly worked. I mean that the TextView and button worked but there are no names in the list from the android phone's contacts. I had even tried `SimpleCursorAdapter friendsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_list, c, columns, views);
     SimpleCursorAdapter layoutAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, columns, views);

     this.setListAdapter(friendsAdapter);
     this.setListAdapter(layoutAdapter);` but it still showed the same

Comment: For more information, I used `ContentProvider` and `ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` to the the names from the phone's contacts.